# Is there a better solution to test getters with the Google Test Framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, constructor, googletest, getter

I am testing the getters of a class. Each getter has some regex code to validate the input.

I use the Google Test Framework to write the unit tests.

Every time I want to test a new getter I need to expand the parameters of the constructor. I need to update the code of the previous tests to not break the previous tests.

Like this:

```
TEST_F(wsRecordTest,DoesItThrowExceptionWhenWrongCitynameIsProvided)
{
    weatherdayRecord wsRecord{"!#Delft$*"}; --> has to be: weatherdayRecord wsRecord{"!#Delft$*","2020-10-03"}; 
    ASSERT_THROW(wsRecord.getCity(),std::invalid_argument);
}

// Test accessor getDate() and constructor
TEST_F(wsRecordTest,DoIGetTheRightDateFromTheConstructor)
{
    weatherdayRecord wsRecord{"Delft","2020-10-03"};
    ASSERT_EQ(wsRecord.getDate(),"2020-10-03");
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Create factory method?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a SetUp functionality to your fixture?

```
class wsRecordTest : public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
        std::unique_ptr<weatherdayRecord> record;
        void SetUp() override {
            record = std::make_unique<weatherdayRecord>("Delft", "2020-10-03");
        }
}

TEST_F(wsRecotdTest, CheckDate) {
     ASSERT_EQ(record->getDate(), "2020-10-03");
}
```

Not sure though why you want to test your getters if the classes are just holders for data..

Comment: I want to modify the call to the constructor with each test, because I want to test the regex with each getter. If I use the above feature I can't do that. Or I need to create a 'record' object for each test. Which is basically the same I am doing now.